# Understanding the use of bitwise operators in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, bit-manipulation

Can someone explain the purpose of using bitwise operators(like BIT_OR) in MySQL queries. For example, if have a table such as following:

[image]

What is the purpose of aggregate operation like:

```
SELECT name FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING BIT_OR(value) = 0;
```

What exactly does the `BIT_OR` do? I understand the actual operation of converting two integers to binary and determining if each pair of corresponding digits are either 0 or 1(if at least one of them is a 1), but what happens with varchar or other non-number columns columns? I know for example, SUM aggregate function can give me the sum of a column of each group. Likewise, what does `BIT_OR` tell me for each group?

**NOTE:**I randomly created the above table and query - it doesn't illustrate any specific problem

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#bit-operations-bit-aggregate - note that it is an *aggregate* function, like SUM, and applies to all values for the column within a group: so BIT_OR(a) = a1 | a2 | a3 .., just as SUM(a) = a1 + a2 + a3 .. Only the operator applied differs.

Comment: Now the “use” of such.. uhh, never felt/had the need for such, however there is likely some applications using such in a specific problem implementation, with some meaningful bitfield definition *shrug*

Comment: (In the specific case of comparing BIT_OR(a) = 0: it will only be true if all values are NULL or 0. This could also be done with a count-case.)

Comment: [Answered on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262492/understanding-the-use-of-bitwise-operators-in-mysql/262493#262493) without success. Ask a meaningful clarifying question. I suspect the first comment here is sufficient.

Comment: @danblack I need to see a use case/purpose of this? I know what it is doing which you have explained but why would I ever need to use it??

Comment: If you want to select a groups where all the values in each group are 0. Its usually seen as `HAVING SUM(value)=0` which has the same effect. I suspect SUM comes more naturally to programmers/DBAs writing application code than `BIT_OR`.